# Team Foundation Server - Unable To Queue New Builds

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Does anybody have any experience with TFS no longer letting somebody queue a new build?

Everybody else on my team can still queue new builds, but when i try to, it shows a little red 'x' as tho it can't connect to that part of the server.

I'm still able to check in/out code and get latest versions, but I can no longer queue up the builds.

There have been no recent configuration changes on my machine that would not have also been preformed on all other team machines. I have the proper security to access the builds and queue new ones.

I've tried every from of restarting/reconnecting to the server short of re-installing visual studio.

Anybody have any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you do it from Team System Web Access or does it affect VS only?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Team System Web Access.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892990.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3ECD00BA-972B-4120-A8D5-3D38311893DE&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stemmed from the Team Foundation package being shut off.

First, Close Visual Studio

Then, in the Visual Studo Command Prompt Run the command

```
devenv /ResetSkipPkgs
```

And you will be ready to go when you open visual studio back up.

Comment: Very cool. I really didn't want to export/delete/import all my settings. This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the build agent down?  Meaning the server that is actually running the build is offline or shutdown?  If the build agent is unreachable you will get the behavior you are experiencing.  Check if its down by going into team explorer then right clicking on builds and then left clicking on manage build agents from the context menu.  I am assuming you are dealing with TFS 2008.

Comment: No context menu appears when i right click on the builds folder. I'm the only person on my team having this problem. The folder has a little red X on it showing like it was unable to find it on the server.

Comment: Well the only other thing I can think of is that you don't have the right permission (your user) or are not in the right group in the tfs groups.  On the project someone with higher permissions than yours can right click and bring up the team project settings context menu then click on permissions.  This will bring up the project security settings dialog.  Make sure that either your user or the group you are in has the Start A Build permission to Allow checked.

Answer (score 0):

Red X on a single user almost always means a permissions problem when talking about the Documents or Reports nodes, but would be quite strange for Builds.  My guess is some sort of connectivity problem, such as an errant proxy.  I'd use Fiddler2 to troubleshoot.  (granted, you have to have some idea what "normal" Fiddler traces look like -- maybe diff your traces against one of your coworkers who doesn't have the issue)